# How do I get the client side final redirected page using PHP curl?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I am trying to scrape a website 'http://www.motorsingh.com/red-olx-cars-in-gulabpura'. 
But this does a javascript redirect to 404 after the page is loaded with a 200 success code.

How can I get this final redirected url using PHP Curl?

PS: Have tried CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. Dint work.

Comment: Get html content before in temp file and parse it after

Comment: i can't visit the page you linked.. it's actually a real 404 i guess (you might get a 200 response because of the way the website handles not found posts)

Comment: No. its not. it returns a 200 status code. Some javascript function gets the data and based on that they move the site to 404 :-\

Comment: what i mean it's that the post you want to access doesn't exist, are you actually trying to scrape their 404 page? doesn't really make sense imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a JS redirect purely in curl - you will need a JS interpreter to go further.

There are some horrendous half-working hacks, like regexing out a URL from the page contents, but it's a bad idea and difficult to maintain.